# Google map + jQuery: rendering bug

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, google-maps

When placing a google map inside a jquery-ui tab, the map fails to display properly in certain circumstances. To reproduce:

1. Go [here](http://www.fiveminuteargument.com/html/map-test.html)
2. Click the 'list' link
3. Resize the browser window
4. Click the 'map' link

Observe that some of the place name overlays draw properly, but others do not. I've actually stripped out all of the jquery-ui stuff to limit the scope of the problem, and it appears to be just the application of display:hide/display:block that causes the problem.

**UPDATE**

The bug also occurs, occasionally, just when toggling between display:none/block - e.g. no resizing occurs. This seems to be most common in IE(8).

Comment: Is this for Google Maps API v2 or v3? I've been working with v3 and have been having similar problems, but haven't yet been able to solved them 100%.

Comment: I solved that problem let's have a look on http://stackoverflow.com/a/13380866/1823525

Answer (score 3):

Try calling `map.onResize()` after you show the map each time.

It may not work fine if it is called when the map is hidden using display:none since it would have zero height and width.

Comment: Yup, the display: none is definitely the problem.

Answer (score 3):

From the [online docs](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/):

> Use the off-left technique for hiding
>   inactive tab panels. E.g. in your
>   style sheet replace the rule for the
>   class selector ".ui-tabs .ui-tabs-hide" with
>
> ```
> .ui-tabs .ui-tabs-hide {
>     position: absolute;
>     left: -10000px;
> }
> ```

Answer (score 3):

Using the [jQuery Google Maps plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/jquery-googlemap) is was having the same issue with jQuery UI tabs.

The map is created like this:

```
$("#google-map").googlemap({
    controls: false,
    labels: true,
    zoom: 9,
    latitude: 51.5,
    longitude: 0,
    debug: false
});
```

It was solved very easily (but not quickly) by calling

```
$("#google-map").googlemap().getMap().checkResize();
```

After the map `div` is displayed. I have tested this on FF and Safari, in addition

```
resizeTo(screen.width, screen.height);
```

Works in FF but not IE or Safari.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
  if (window.attachEvent) { 
    window.attachEvent("onresize", function() {this.map.onResize()} );
  } else {
    window.addEventListener("resize", function() {this.map.onResize()} , false);
  }
```

after

```
map_initialize();
```

because you have to tell the map that the page is resized, maybe that's the problem you are having not a jquery one

**EDIT**

Ok 
remove the

```
if (window.attachEvent) { 
            window.attachEvent("onresize", function() {map.onResize()} );
        } else {
            window.addEventListener("resize", function() {map.onResize()} , false);
        }
```

and replace your

```
$('#map').show();
```

with:

```
 $("#map").show(1, function () {
          resizeMap();
        });
```

> resizeMap() will call Google Maps'
>   checkResize() on the particular map.

source: http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/#...my_slider.2C_Google_Map.2C_sIFR_etc._not_work_when_placed_in_a_hidden_.28inactive.29_tab.3F

Comment: Sounds nice in theory, but doesn't work for me in practice :( (example updated)

Comment: your updated example don't have the problem any more for me,
I'm using firefox 3.5 what are you using?

Comment: Firefox 3.5.1 I'll try in a couple of other browsers - wonder if I've got some caching issues. I'll post a couple of screenshots if the problem persists, just to confirm what it is. Cheers.

Comment: I updated to 3.5.1 and I don't see the problem as well, please post the screenshots

Comment: I actually get an error with this line in IE8:
window.attachEvent("onresize", function() {map.onResize()} );

(should that REALLY be 'onResize'?)

Comment: That didn't work either (where is the resizeMap function actually defined??) but the other info. on that page helped - thanks!