# Google Maps Api v3 Maps in Ui-Tabs are cut

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, tabs

I know this is a common problem here, i already look at all the topics here for a solution, but still, when i change tabs i continue with this problem:

[image]

please take a look at my js code:

```
  function initialize() {

//replace 0's on next line with latitude and longitude numbers from earlier on in tutorial.
var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(40.654372, -7.914174);
var myLatlng1 = new google.maps.LatLng(43.654372, -7.914174);
    var myOptions = {
      zoom: 16,
      center: myLatlng,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }

    var myOptions1 = {
      zoom: 16,
      center: myLatlng1,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }

//here's where we call the marker.
//getElementById must be the same as the id you gave for the container of the map
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);
var map1 = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas1"), myOptions1);
 //google.maps.event.trigger(map1, 'resize');
 //map1.setCenter(myLatlng1);

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: myLatlng,
      title:"ADD TITLE OF YOUR MARKER HERE"
  });

        var marker1 = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: myLatlng1,
      title:"ADD TITLE OF YOUR MARKER HERE"
  });

        var contentString = '<div id="content">'+
    '<div id="siteNotice">'+
    '<\/div>'+
    '<h2 id="firstHeading" class="firstHeading">ADD TITLE HERE<\/h2>'+
    '<div id="bodyContent">'+
    '<p style="font-size:1em">ADD DESCRIPTION HERE<\/p>'+
    '<\/div>'+
    '<\/div>';

var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: contentString
});

google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
  infowindow.open(map,marker);
});

google.maps.event.addListener(marker1, 'click', function() {
  infowindow.open(map1,marker1);
}); 

google.maps.event.addListener(map, "idle", function(){
    marker.setMap(map); 
});

google.maps.event.addListener(map, "idle", function(){
    marker1.setMap(map1);
});  


  // To add the marker to the map, call setMap();



  google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, 'idle', function() {
    google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
    map.setCenter(myLatlng); // be sure to reset the map center as well
});

google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map1, 'idle', function() {
    google.maps.event.trigger(map1, 'resize');
    map1.setCenter(myLatlng1); // be sure to reset the map center as well
});


  }


  function loadScript() {
    var script = document.createElement("script");
    script.type = "text/javascript";
    script.src = "http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&callback=initialize";
    document.body.appendChild(script);
  }

  window.onload = loadScript;
```

i have two maps, one ofr each tab. i could solve the problem of the center point being hide on the left corner with this from other post:

```
    .ui-tabs .ui-tabs-hide { /* my_tabs-1 contains google map */
    display: block !important;
    position: absolute !important;
    left: -10000px !important;
    top: -10000px !important;
}
```

but the problem stated here i had no luck even lookin at other topics here.

Answer (score 7):

I found the clean solution:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
         function showAddressMap(){
                var mapOptions = {    
                          zoom: 15,
                          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
                         }

                var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);

                 geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
            // searchQuery is the address I used this in a JSP so I called with $
                 geocoder.geocode( {'address': "${searchQuery}"}, function(results, status) {
                        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                          map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
                          var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                              map: map,
                              position: results[0].geometry.location
                          });
                        } else {
                          alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
                        }
                 });
                 google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');

             //}
          }

          JQ(document).ready(function(){
            JQ('#tabs').tabs();
            JQ('#maptab').bind('click', function() {
                showAddressMap();
            });
          });
        </script>



    <div id="tabs">
        <li><a href="#tabs-1" id="maptab"><fmt:message key="fieldset.map"/></a></li>
    </div>
    <div id="tabs-1">
    <fieldset>
            <div id="map_canvas" style="height:500px; width:100%;"></div>
    </fieldset>
    </div>
```

Comment: This did the trick. Make shure the tab is showing, otherwise gmaps is only showing an empty canvas.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the center and trigger a re-size event.

```
MyMap.setCenter(MyCenterCoords);
google.maps.event.trigger(MyMap, 'resize');
```

Comment: Lewis thanks for the reply, you can check my code above, i'm already doing that.

Comment: Actually, you're doing that inside of the 'idle' event handler. You have to do that at the moment you show your tab. After your tab was shown, resize your browser window and you will see it get fixed. Once your tab is shown, you need to set the center and fire the event.

Comment: Hmm, but then where should i do that? Can you give me an hint please?

Comment: Not sure what framework you're using for your tabs. You can certainly bind on the show event of the tab.

Answer (score 0):

This code google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize') should be in the pageshow like below.

```
$('#map_result').live('pageshow',function(event){
    google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');
});
```

By the way, have you found the solutions for this? I actually make it works using css.

Answer (score 0):

I know its not a elegant solution, but you can just add an Iframe inside each tab. and when you click the tab, the map load with the correct sizes.